# Laravel 5.5 : getting error while creating project

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a project of Laravel (version 5.5) in Ubuntu (version 16.04) but while i running it on browser, getting error like this:

> syntax error, unexpected '?' in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/lara1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 233

I have searched a lot for this and got that there are some version problem (displaying PHP version 5.6 on browser and in CLI it's 7.0) so i'm trying to remove the PHP version 5.6 by using command

```
apt-get purge 'php5*'
```

but its showing :

> Package 'php5.6-common' is not installed, so not removed

So how can i remove php 5.6 from cli and run laravel project without getting error.

I'm new to Laravel and Ubuntu.

Please help me to get this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited :**

while running sudo apt remove php5.6 getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5.6-json' for regex 'php5.6'
Note, selecting 'php5.6-common' for regex 'php5.6'
Package 'php5.6-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php5.6-json' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8:i386 libmircommon5 libpango1.0-0 libsnapd-glib1
linux-headers-4.4.0-71 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72
linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75
linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-78
linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-79
linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-81
linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-83
linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-87
linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-89
linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-92
linux-headers-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-89-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic snapd-login-service ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 212 not upgraded.
```

Comment: sudo apt remove php5.6

Comment: and don't forget to install php7

Comment: Laravel 5.5 requires php version 7.0 or above

Comment: @Deepak Kumar T P ..please look at my edited part.

Comment: Package 'php5.6-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php5.6-json' is not installed, so not removed 
these two lines confusing me.what's going worng with this.

Comment: @Shobi P P... in cli it's 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to remove the old PHP.It is indicate the php interpreter is 7 but the php-fpm is 5.6. This because the port 9000 is listened by the php-fpm that belong to php56.So you should stop all the process about php-fpm

```
sudo killall php-fpm  // or sudo pkill -9 php-fpm
```

then go to the php7 folder and run the php-fpm process.
 Hope it helps.
 what's more,you have the right direction. Laravel5.5 need php7 or higher.Good luck!